# Android Paypal payment verification

Tags: android, paypal

I would like to know where in the **Android App** do I place the code that gives Paypal payment status ? Is it in the payment activity.java file in my Android app? The code I am speaking of is :

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}"
```

I have read the API documents but I do not find where or how to implement the verification process

the link is: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/#looking-up-a-payment-using-the-rest-api

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

PayPal already have an [SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) that explains how to implement its service, please take a look in an Full implementation of an Activity with Payment and Verification.
Link for the [source](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp)

You have to configure the `PayPalConfiguration` variable with the corresponding of the console.

The `onActivityResult` have all verification from the payment that you need.

NOTE: You can use SandBox for do tests just getting an SandBox client ID from the console and adding it to the constant `CONFIG_CLIENT_ID`.

Take a look in the Full Implementation bellow:

```
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalItem;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalOAuthScopes;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPaymentDetails;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ShippingAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Basic sample using the SDK to make a payment or consent to future payments.
 * 
 * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
 * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
 */
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "paymentExample";
    /**
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
     * 
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials
     * from https://developer.paypal.com
     * 
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires
     * without communicating to PayPal's servers.
     */
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "credential from developer.paypal.com";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING = 3;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
            // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName("Example Merchant")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
        /* 
         * PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
         * Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to 
         *   - PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only authorize payment and capture funds later.
         *   - PAYMENT_INTENT_ORDER to create a payment for authorization and capture
         *     later via calls from your server.
         * 
         * Also, to include additional payment details and an item list, see getStuffToBuy() below.
         */
        PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        /*
         * See getStuffToBuy(..) for examples of some available payment options.
         */

        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
    }

    private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
        return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "sample item",
                paymentIntent);
    }

    /* 
     * This method shows use of optional payment details and item list.
     */
    private PayPalPayment getStuffToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
        //--- include an item list, payment amount details
        PayPalItem[] items =
            {
                    new PayPalItem("sample item #1", 2, new BigDecimal("87.50"), "USD",
                            "sku-12345678"),
                    new PayPalItem("free sample item #2", 1, new BigDecimal("0.00"),
                            "USD", "sku-zero-price"),
                    new PayPalItem("sample item #3 with a longer name", 6, new BigDecimal("37.99"),
                            "USD", "sku-33333") 
            };
        BigDecimal subtotal = PayPalItem.getItemTotal(items);
        BigDecimal shipping = new BigDecimal("7.21");
        BigDecimal tax = new BigDecimal("4.67");
        PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(shipping, subtotal, tax);
        BigDecimal amount = subtotal.add(shipping).add(tax);
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(amount, "USD", "sample item", paymentIntent);
        payment.items(items).paymentDetails(paymentDetails);

        //--- set other optional fields like invoice_number, custom field, and soft_descriptor
        payment.custom("This is text that will be associated with the payment that the app can use.");

        return payment;
    }

    /*
     * Add app-provided shipping address to payment
     */
    private void addAppProvidedShippingAddress(PayPalPayment paypalPayment) {
        ShippingAddress shippingAddress =
                new ShippingAddress().recipientName("Mom Parker").line1("52 North Main St.")
                        .city("Austin").state("TX").postalCode("78729").countryCode("US");
        paypalPayment.providedShippingAddress(shippingAddress);
    }

    /*
     * Enable retrieval of shipping addresses from buyer's PayPal account
     */
    private void enableShippingAddressRetrieval(PayPalPayment paypalPayment, boolean enable) {
        paypalPayment.enablePayPalShippingAddressesRetrieval(enable);
    }

    public void onFuturePaymentPressed(View pressed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
    }

    public void onProfileSharingPressed(View pressed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PayPalProfileSharingActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_REQUESTED_SCOPES, getOauthScopes());

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING);
    }

    private PayPalOAuthScopes getOauthScopes() {
        /* create the set of required scopes
         * Note: see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/ for mapping between the
         * attributes you select for this app in the PayPal developer portal and the scopes required here.
         */
        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>(
                Arrays.asList(PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_EMAIL, PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_ADDRESS) );
        return new PayPalOAuthScopes(scopes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        /**
                         *  TODO: send 'confirm' (and possibly confirm.getPayment() to your server for verification
                         * or consent completion.
                         * See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                         * for more details.
                         *
                         * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
                         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
                         */
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Future Payment code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("FuturePaymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "FuturePaymentExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            } 
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Profile Sharing code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("ProfileSharingExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "ProfileSharingExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

        /**
         * TODO: Send the authorization response to your server, where it can
         * exchange the authorization code for OAuth access and refresh tokens.
         * 
         * Your server must then store these tokens, so that your server code
         * can execute payments for this user in the future.
         * 
         * A more complete example that includes the required app-server to
         * PayPal-server integration is available from
         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
         */

    }

    public void onFuturePaymentPurchasePressed(View pressed) {
        // Get the Client Metadata ID from the SDK
        String metadataId = PayPalConfiguration.getClientMetadataId(this);

        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "Client Metadata ID: " + metadataId);

        // TODO: Send metadataId and transaction details to your server for processing with
        // PayPal...
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(), "Client Metadata Id received from SDK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop service when done
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok so I did not use the code you pasted but I did implement the SDK and in the log I see it reports the sale succeeded in sandbox of course. This is all the verification I need correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the Payment payament status api in the Android App.

Instead, the SDK will be more than enough to return the status of the payment made via App. You need to use the Paypal Android SDK mentioned in the developer docs - [Paypal Mobile SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/).

The SDK will handle all the calls required for completing a transaction. You just need to provide the PayPalConfiguration attributes required for starting the transaction. Once the transaction completes, the OnActivityResult will have the status of transaction, status codes etc. based on which you can determine the transaction status.

If you do have to use the Paypal payment status api then you should be using it from your server as a backup for the transaction that have completed at paypal but the response was not received at your server or your application.

For this - setup a cron and designate a particular status for these type of transactions like Pending Payment. In the cron, you can get the response of all the orders and process them based on completion status.